# Question on a simple proof of Jordan Normal Form

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, jordan-normal-form

I am currently a year 2 uni mathematician, understanding the Jordan Normal Form in Linear Algebra.

Here is a paper for a short proof of the Jordan Normal Form, which I am looking at in order to understand it:

[http://www.ma.rhul.ac.uk/~uvah099/Maths/JNFfinal.pdf](http://www.ma.rhul.ac.uk/%7Euvah099/Maths/JNFfinal.pdf)

It reduces the proof down to the following statement:

If $T: V \to V$ is a linear transformation of a finite-dimensional vector space such that $T^m = 0$ for some $m \geq 1$, then there is a basis of $V$ of the form

$u_1, T(u_1), \dots, T^{a_1 - 1}(u_1), \dots, u_k, T(u_k), \dots, T^{a_k - 1} (u_k)$

where $T^{a_i}(u_i) = 0$ for $1 \leq i \leq k$.

I am currently struggling to understand the proof, and how the adjoined elements $w_1, \dots, w_m$ are in fact of the form described in the theorem. That is, how can we show that $w_1, \dots, w_m$ are also something like $v,T(v), \dots, T^{m-1}(v)$?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this seems good https://www.maths.tcd.ie/~vdots/teaching/files/MA1111+1212-0809/JordanExample.pdf     You want, given a matrix  $A$ of integers with integer eigenvalues,  to be able to construct an (integer)  matrix $P,$  all by hand, such that $P^{-1}AP = J$  is in Jordan Form.  You say you are at university, the skill will help. The two main simple applications, find all $A^n$   or find $e^{At}$  need the actual matrix $P,$  not just $J$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us call $v, T(v), \ldots, T^{m-1}(v)$, where $T^m(v) = 0$, the cycle generated by $v$.  The point is to get a basis that can be viewed as a union of disjoint cycles.  In the proof you linked the vectors $w_1, \ldots, w_m$ are all taken from $\ker(T)$, so they have $T(w_i) = 0$ for all $i$.  Another way of saying that is that the cycle generated by $w_i$ is just $w_i$ itself, so we're just adding a bunch of cycles of length $1$ here.